# Big query issue

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables table 1 and table 2.

**Table 1**

| id | name | usage | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | HD. | 5000 | 12 |

**Table 2**

| id | name | usage_cost | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | HD. | O | 0 |
| 111 | HD. | 1000. | 20 |
| 111 | HD. | 3000. | 30 |
| 111 | HD. | 4000. | 40 |

Now I need to join two tables and get usage amount by multiplying usage  from table 1 with amount from table 2.

Example

```
Usage 5000
First 0 to 1000 it should multiply with 0 
In remaining 4000
Then 1000 to 3000 it should be multiple with 20
In Remaining 2000 
Then 3000 to 4000 it should be multiple with 30

Amount 2000*20 and 1000 *30 and remaining 1000 *40

       40000
       30000
       40000
Total 110000
```

By joing two table

```
id  name  usage usage.amount
111.   Hd.  5000. 110000

Amount 2000*20 and 1000 *30 and remaining 1000 *40

       40000
       30000
       40000
Total 110000
```

By joing two table

| id | name | usage | usage_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | HD. | 5000. | 110000 |

I have many I'd in tables, so I cannot hardcode the amount for each I'd . It should be automatically done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) in a few step to get the result you want.

step 1:  Use window function and lead()/lag() to get bound and cost of each cost tier

step 2:  Use window function and sum() to calculate cost amount up to current tier

Step 3:  Join with user table and search for the current tier for the user based on usage amount, calcuate the total based on tier and remaining amount.

Here is the [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kzPckRGEGDcvDhNtgXQ82h/2):

```
with table2_bound AS (
select
    id,
    name,
    usage_cost,
    amount,
    lag(usage_cost) over (partition by id, name order by usage_cost) as lower_bound_cost,
    lead(usage_cost) over (partition by id, name order by usage_cost) as upper_bound_cost,
    lag(amount) over (partition by id, name order by usage_cost) as lower_bound_amount
from
    table2
),
table2_tier_amount AS (
select
    id,
    name,
    usage_cost,
    amount,
    lower_bound_cost,
    upper_bound_cost,
    lower_bound_amount,
    sum((usage_cost-lower_bound_cost)*lower_bound_amount) over (partition by id, name order by usage_cost) as lower_tier_amount
from
    table2_bound
)
select
   table2_tier_amount.id,
   table2_tier_amount.name,
   usage,
   coalesce(lower_tier_amount,0) + (usage-usage_cost) * amount as usage_amount
   
from
    table2_tier_amount
JOIN
    table1
ON
    table2_tier_amount.id = table1.id
AND
    table2_tier_amount.name = table1.name
where
    usage > amount and (usage< upper_bound_cost or upper_bound_cost is null)
```

| id | name | usage | usage_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | HD. | 5000 | 110000 |